# Key error in nested loop with nested if statements

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops, keyerror

I need to match 2 databases, so I have written a nested for-loop which iterates over database 1, and creates dataframes from database 2, based on set conditions.
The loop iterates over this created dataframe again in order to find a string match with a fuzzy-wuzzy ratio of over 90%, else try another matching ratio.

If one of these ratio's meets the desired similarity the goal is to add the account number from our database "crm" to the "dgh" database

I get a key error 9, suggesting me that it can't find the 9th row in the dataframe? It is referring to the parent loop.

I was wondering if the error is caused because the nested if statement in the nested loop cant access a variable from the parent loop anymore or something like that. If that makes any sense.
In the output it does not only give me the error, but also prints the last else statement multiple times, I do not understand why that happens because I feel like it should run into the error before it can actually run the last else statement.

"dgh" is a dataframe containing customer data we get from our wholesalers

"crm" is customer data from our dynamics system

Here is my code together with the complete error message:

```
for i, row in dgh.iterrows():
dgh_key = dgh.iloc[i]['addresskey']
dgh_name = dgh.iloc[i]['DGH_custname']
temp_key = crm.loc[crm['addresskey'] == dgh_key]
temp_key.reset_index(inplace=True)
for u, row in temp_key.iterrows():
    crm_name = temp_key.iloc[u]['name']
    accountnumber = temp_key.iloc[u]['accountnumber']
    if ((fuzz.ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 60)):
        dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
        break
    elif (fuzz.partial_ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 90):
        dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
        break
    elif (fuzz.token_set_ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 90):
        dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
        break
    else:
        break
if (math.isnan(dgh.iloc[i]['crm_ref']) == False):
    break
else:
    dgh_city = dgh.iloc[i]['DGH_custcity']
    temp_city = crm.loc[crm['address1_city'] == dgh_city]
    temp_city.reset_index(inplace=True)
    for y, row in temp_city.iterrows():
        crm_name = temp_city.iloc[y]['name']
        accountnumber = temp_city.iloc[y]['accountnumber']
        if ((fuzz.ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 60)):
            dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
            break
        elif (fuzz.partial_ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 90):
            dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
            break
        elif (fuzz.token_set_ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 90):
            dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
            break
        else:
            break
if (math.isnan(dgh.iloc[i]['crm_ref']) == False):
    break
else:
    print('No match found')
```

error:

```
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 9

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 1>()
      8 accountnumber = temp_key.iloc[u]['accountnumber']
      9 if ((fuzz.ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 60)):
---> 10     dgh[i]['crm_ref'] = accountnumber
     11     break
     12 elif (fuzz.partial_ratio(dgh_name.lower(), crm_name.lower()) >= 90):

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 9
```

Comment: When you use dgh[i]['crm_ref'], You are trying to assign to index i but instead it looks for column i. 
You should use dgh.loc[i,'crm_ref'] = accountnumber

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that you could give the params to .loc like this. At least the code did something!!